# How to get currently using module/App name in ODOO 12

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo, odoo-12

I want to get the name of the currently used module in ODOO.

suppose there are  different **module named A,B,C,D**. And each module has the same **models like accounts, crm, hr, payroll, etc.**

so I want to make changes in the **payroll** model of **A** module without affecting the **inherited payroll** model of **other Modules**.

so I want to get currently using the module/app name. Is there any code in python odoo

Comment: crm, hr and payroll are modules not models, maybe you want to edit `crm.lead` or ` hr.employee`. Can you please paste your code or anything that is in your mind here so we can check together?

Comment: In invoicing module , want to inherit  "account.payment" model.  Inherited in anothere module A. so i want to make changes in A module without affectoing account.payment in Invoicing-@PMN

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with the `active_model` context value, for example, you can use

```py
if self._context.get('active_model') == 'account.invoice':
   # Your code here
```